# When using two filters in a cell array, an error is raised when a filter has no matches

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I want to look through two small ranges, on another, sheet for rows with a certain string, then remove a column from the results and print them out in a list.

Here is my code:

```
={FILTER( FILTER(General!A6:D, SEARCH("Kevin's Credit",General!D6:D)), {TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}); FILTER( FILTER(General!K6:N, SEARCH("Kevin's Credit",General!N6:N)), {TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE})}
```

If both ranges have the string at least once it will print out all rows that have it. If even one range doesn't have it, neither print and it shows an error;

> Error in ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with a construction such as

```
={filter(A:B, B:B > 5); {true, false}}
```

is that when there are no rows matching the criterion B:B > 5, the array evaluates to

```
={#N/A; {true, false}}
```

where #N/A occupies a single cell. This is a malformed array, with one cell in the 1st row and two in the 2nd row.

You can get around this by replacing a single #N/A with several ones, to have the appropriate number of columns in any event.

```
={iferror(filter(A:B, B:B > 5), {na(), na()}; {true, false}}
```

Of course, something other than na() can be used here.

---

Also, in your specific case you don't need the row with true-false values and the outer filter by them. Just don't include columns D or N in the first place:

```
={filter(General!A6:C, search("Kevin's Credit", General!D6:D)); filter(General!K6:M, search("Kevin's Credit", General!N6:N))}
```

or, in the #N/A-safe form,

```
={iferror(
    filter(General!A6:C, search("Kevin's Credit", General!D6:D)),
    {na(), na(), na()}); 
  iferror(
    filter(General!K6:M, search("Kevin's Credit", General!N6:N)),
    {na(), na(), na()})
 }
```

The second argument of the filter command can be separate from the first; all that matters is that they have the same number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This solution gets me close but leaves a row of #NA cells which is less than ideal. I figured I could make the row empty by swapping `{na(), na(), na()}` with `{"","",""}` but that leaves a blank row still if the first filter has no matching results. Can you help me find  way to omit the row entirely so I can clean this up?

Comment: Maybe wrap the formula in `=query(..., "select * where Col1<>'' ")`, assuming the first column of resulting thing can't be nonempty. Or use something like `Col1 <> 'NO_RESULTS'`, where NO_RESULTS is a string you put instead of n/a.